# homonym, do words such as Conviction, Commitment, Dissipation fit as homonyms also?

Tags: meaning

With the strong assumption that a word like "right" is a homonym, do words such as Conviction, Commitment, Dissipation fit as homonyms also? Or is there some core to the varied definitions and usages of words like the latter three that puts them an a different category.

Comment: A word cannot be a homonym in isolation.  "Right" and "write" are homonyms.  ("homonym: each of two or more words having the same spelling or pronunciation but different meanings and origins.")  Did you perhaps mean *synonym*?

Comment: would "right" used as the opposite direction to left, "right" as in correct, "right" as your opportunity to act and to be treated in particular ways that the law promises to protect for the benefit of society (e.g. civil right) make it a true homonym? Then "conviction" defined as either strong beliefs, or a being found guilty would be considered a weak homonym or maybe a Polyseme?

Comment: Polyseme seems best because the same word is being used in different ways.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy  Homographs/phones/nyms are coincidental, having different origins. https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/homonym-homophone-homograph/

Comment: If it's used in a completely different way it's a completely different word. _Bear_ the verb and _bear_ the animal are not the same word, and both are different from _bare_ the adjective. One can't repeat too often, it appears, that **spelling is irrelevant** in determining English words -- not only doesn't English spelling represent English sounds, it doesn't in fact represent anything at all, since it's a jumble of borrowed spellings and misspellings.